# Intellisense in rehosted workflow designer

Tags: .net, intellisense, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to enable intellisense in the rehosted workflow designer (as like in Visual studio)? if yes, how?

edit: the answer might be [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/cb550f4f-37c4-4d58-bf27-b5c0710c60a0), but I am afraid the posts' language are too technical and I don't truly understand what's being said

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to implement IExpressionEditorService and add that to your WorkflowDesigner. Check out [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/07f89fc0-81ff-4e85-a974-013b15b62f50) series of posts for a solution that is build on top of the VS2010 assemblies.

Comment: do you mean the posts by Flowster or Brannon? Flowster's solution has questionable legality and involves copying some VS2010 dlls. And brannon's solution doesn't work (he admitted that in his posts)

Comment: The solution by Flowster. It requires VS2010, not sure if the express version is enough, but I was under the impression that you could use the DLL's legally in that case (but I am not a lawyer and didn't consult one on this matter either). Shipping the DLL's with your app is certainly illegal but it the end user downloads and installs VS2010 express...

Answer (score 1):

I came across a project with working IntelliSense enabled.

http://wfdesignerexpress.codeplex.com/

It is accomplished using custom ExpressionEditor and reflection. Unfortunately this project is written in VB.NET and its GUI and some of the comments are in japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the many rabbit holes this line of enquiry leads to - eventually we went to the very helpful Actipro software who provide an Intelliprompt WPF control. They even wrote up the solution as a 'tip and trick' to guide us in how to use the control to achieve our goal.
http://blog.actiprosoftware.com/post/2013/08/26/Enhancing-the-Windows-Workflow-Designer.aspx